# Restore os-prober script in /etc/grub.d

Tags: software-installation, grub2

I accidentally removed `30_os-prober` script in the directory `/etc/grub.d`.
How can I restore it without reinstalling Grub?
I didn't find any manual or command list for `os-prober`.

I'm on ArchLinux 3.10.25 x64 and use Grub 2.00.1282.

Comment: Uninstall and Reinstall os-prober package ?

Comment: @Sigma It hasn't helped

Comment: Why not just reinstall grub? It won't affect the actual bootloader unless you re-run `grub-install`.

Comment: @terdon i didn't think about it and it seemed that other ways existed.

Comment: Yes you can and you [should](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132886/203101).

Comment: @terdon I will be able to do it after 2 days

Comment: Yes, sorry, the _should_ was not meant as a command. It's up to you of course, I just meant that it is completely OK to accept your own answer and that that way, the question is marked as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the `30_os-prober` script from the Grub package. In the case of Arch Linux: `/var/cache/pacman/pkg/grub*.tar.xz` if you didn't clean the package cache.

Comment: I didn't really understand the package name you use could you [edit] your question to make it a bit clearer ?

Comment: @Kiwy I think that it's a grub 2.00.1282